# Can Mages of the same Tradition but different non-Affinity Spheres use the same Sanctum?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

There are two Virtual Adepts. One has the Spheres Correspondence 3/Matter 2/Forces 2 while the other has Correspondence 3/Life 2/Mind 2. They share the same Affinity Sphere (Correspondence) and have the same Paradigm (Everything is Data) and Practice (Reality Hacking). They want to pool their Background to create a Sanctum together. However, given their different Spheres they utilize a number of different Instruments. They have some degree of overlay with their Instruments (Computers and Laboratory Gear come to mind), but for a number of things they use Instruments that only one of them uses and the other not. The rules for Sanctums however suggests that they cannot build a Sanctum that covers them both:

> The Effects of rival mages are considered vulgar in your space. That Man in Black’s procedures go against the prevailing reality within that witch’s sanctuary, whereas the witch’s spells run counter to the established reality of a NWO Construct. Rivals who use the same style of magick would be considered equally at home in a Sanctum – two Verbenae, for example, who hate each other’s guts but who employ the same paradigms and tools would both be considered coincidental within the same sanctum; an Etherite, however, would find that her weird science is vulgar within that witch’s sacred ground, even if she was allied with one of the rival Verbenae.

(Mage the Ascension 20th Anniversary, p. 324)

So can these two Virtual Adepts of mismatched Spheres and Tools use a Sanctum that holds everything that they can use, but also things that only the other can use? Or is it because of some RAW clause that only a Mage that uses all Instruments that the two of them combined use function in a Sanctum like this?

Comment: Your question seems to contain your answer and you do not seem to be pointing to any conflicts with this information, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is actually in the text you quoted. There's a portion that says.

> ...two Verbenae, for example, who hate each other’s guts but who employ the same paradigms and tools would both be considered coincidental within the same sanctum.

If two Verbena can share the same space, two Virtual Adepts would be able to as well. The particular Spheres that the mages use aren't relevant to the Sanctum; What matters is the Paradigm that the mages adhere to. As long as the Paradigm is the same, the prevailing reality of the Sanctum will allow both mages to take advantage of it.

The use of different Instruments isn't an issue, as Instruments are a personal choice of each mage. If Mage A needs a bank of server ranks while Mage B instead relies on a single, sleek computer tower made of black box material, both can exist side by side in the same sanctum without problems.